# How to identify the text that are in common between sentences?

Tags: r

I would like to find the text or string that appeared in 3 of my columns.

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(Jan = "The price of oil declined.", Feb = "The price of gold declined.", 
Mar = "Prices remained unchanged."), row.names = c(NA, -1L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to get something like

```
Word       Count
The        2
price      3
declined   2
of         2
```

Thank you.

Comment: tidytext::unnest_tokens can help here I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code won't process the data as you may wish, for ex. treating "price" and "Prices" as the same word. If you want that it will get more complicated.

```
> data.frame(table(strsplit(tolower(gsub("\\.|\\,","",paste(as.character(unlist(df)),collapse=" ")))," ")))
       Var1 Freq
1  declined    2
2      gold    1
3        of    2
4       oil    1
5     price    2
6    prices    1
7  remained    1
8       the    2
9 unchanged    1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can count the occurrence of each word in the text and keep only the ones that occur more than once.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  separate_rows(value, sep = '\\s+') %>%
  mutate(value = tolower(gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', value))) %>%
  count(value) %>%
  filter(n > 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

May be this:

```
setNames(data.frame(table(unlist
  (strsplit
    (trimws(tolower(stack(df)$values),whitespace = '\\.'), '\\s+',   perl=TRUE)
    )
   )
  ), c('words', 'Frequency'))
```

stack(df) will stack the df to columnar structure from row structure, then using values column we get all the sentences. we use trimws to remove all the unnecessary punctuation. we use strsplit to split data with spaces. Finally unlisting it to make it flatten. Taking the table and then converting to data.frame yields the desired results.setNames renames the columns.

**Output**:

```
#      words Frequency
#1  declined         2
#2      gold         1
#3        of         2
#4       oil         1
#5     price         2
#6    prices         1
#7  remained         1
#8       the         2
#9 unchanged         1
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
setNames(
  data.frame(
    table(
        unlist(strsplit(tolower(do.call(c, df1)), "\\s+|[[:punct:]]"))
      )
    ),
  c("Words", "Frequency")
)
```